# Null result being displayed using jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I am new to the concepts of dynamic web project .I have made the following two JSP and a one java class as just starting experiment.
    The following rae my code

user.java

```
package com;

public class User {

    private String name;
    private int Id;

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

index.jsp

<

```
%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="First.jsp">

name<input type="text" name="name" />
id<input type="text" name="Id" />


            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />

<jsp:useBean id="user" class="com.User" />
            <jsp:setProperty name="user" property="*"/>     




</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and again First.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:useBean id="user" class="com.User" />
user is :<%= user.getName() %><BR>
Id is :<%= user.getId() %><BR>



</body>
</html>
```

But its showing me null for both values.I know its very easy program .But I am not getting the concept correctly

Thanks

Comment: did you create an user instance in somewhere setting properties?

Comment: First of all rename the variable "int Id " to "int id"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" class="com.User" />
<jsp:setProperty name="user" property="*"/>
```

from **index.jsp** to **First.jsp**

The request parameters are submitted to First.jsp and not index.jsp.

```
 <jsp:setProperty name="user" property="*"/>
```

populates user bean's properties with those from the request parameters. The form is submitted to First.jsp, which receives the request parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your `jsp:useBean` in First.jsp creates an instance of `com.User` using the default constructor, which sets both `name` and `id` to null. Therefore, you get null when you print their values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any user object in session so all you need to do now is to make use  of  `jsp:setProperty` tag!.

The `useBean` tag will look for an instance of the "`user`" in the `session`.

If the instance is already there, it will update the old instance.Otherwise, it will create a new instance of user and put it in the session.

You previously doesn't put the `user` bean in the session.So new instance with null values vreated.

[Bean Processing in JSP](http://www.jsptut.com/forms.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting form data to First.jsp. But no where in First.jsp you are handling/ processing request parameters. So, Try something  in First.jsp:

```
 <jsp:useBean id="user" class="com.User" scope = "request" />

<jsp:setProperty property="name" value="<%= request.getParameter("name") %>"name="user" />
<jsp:setProperty property="Id" value="<%= request.getParameter("Id") %> name="user" />

 Name: <jsp:getProperty property = "name" name="user" />
 Id : <jsp:getProperty property = "Id" name="user" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSTL  tag. It has default property for default value. If value is null then default value will be shown.